# If $G/Z(G)$ is finite, then $|G'| < \infty$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite group. Suppose that $G/Z(G)$ is a finite group, where
$$G^{\prime}= \left\langle xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\ \middle\vert\ x,y \in G\right\rangle.$$
Prove that $|G'| < \infty$.

Comment: i have no idea how to start

Comment: The question could show more own efforts, but I can't see what else is wrong about it.

Comment: I know a theorem that says **exactly** the other way around: if $\;[G:Z(G)]<\infty\;$ , then $\;G'\;$ is finite. This one looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @Timbuc Honestly, I don't see whether this is true or not and would be interested in an answer.

Comment: @PeterFranek I can't say, but I can't remember anything of this like. Perhaps it is true, of course, but being the other way around true beyond any doubt, I'd say there's some fair chance the OP confused the data.

Comment: As you have written it, $G'$ is not a group because the product of two commutators is not necessarily a commutator. Also, if you want to take the quotient then you should probably take the normal closure.

Comment: $G'$ is always  normal subgroup og $G$

Comment: An infinite nilpotent group with $G/G^{\prime}$ finite would produce a rather neat counter-example. However, no such groups exist! (See, for example, Robinson *A course in the theory of groups, 5.2.6.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. Let $H$ be a perfect group such that $H' = H$ and $Z(H) \neq 1$ (for example, $SL_n(F)$ for suitable $n$ and $F$) Then for $G = H \oplus H \oplus H \oplus \cdots$ (infinite direct sum), we have $G' = G$ but $Z(G)$ is infinite.

Comment: But $G/G'$ is not finite...

Comment: Exactly, $|\frac{G}{G'}|= 1$ it is not suitble example

Comment: you said  $G=G'$, what is $\frac{G}{G'}$??? Is it infinite?????

Comment: @erfansoheil Mikko answered your question. You cannot prove that $|Z(G)|<\infty$ because the statement is false in general.

Comment: Are you sure that the property that $(A\times B)'=A'\times B'$ also holds for the infinite product? No big deal if not, because it will certainly work with the infinite coproduct.

Comment: To clarify that comment a bit, it could happen that I take some element in $(H'\times H' \times H'\times ...)$ that requires increasingly more commutators to write down in each component then I can't immediately write it as something from $(H\times H\times \dots)'$

Comment: @PeterFranek, he did not answered the question, because hos example is wrong

Comment: @Myself Not that it matters, but I think that for $SL_n(F)$, the number of needed commutators is bounded.. definitely for $F$ finite.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C})$ works (so we do not need the infinite product stuff - I agree with @Myself that this might be dodgy). It is perfect, and has centre containing a copy of $\mathbb{C}$ (specifically, $\{xI:x\in\mathbb{C}\}\leq Z(\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{C}))$). Replacing $\mathbb{C}$ with any infinite field also works... no?

Comment: @user1729 Problem with that is that $\mathrm{det}(xI)=x^2$ so these are not in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\Bbb C)$ except for $I$ and $-I$.

Comment: @Myself: You are probably right! This answer was a bit hasty, we should take the coproduct here.